# Passing PHP Variable echoing HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a .PHP file and wanted to echo HTML. I did echo it perfectly but now i want to echo a javascript onclick= print( $variable) .
I keep getting error or invalid syntax.

the button on click won't work when i pass in a php variable but if i pass in manually it works.

Thank you.

Below are my code.

```
                    <div class="streamline b-l m-l">
                     <?php   
                         $messages = $user_projects_json['projects'][$projectKey]['alarms']; 
                         foreach($messages as $message_key => $messagesList){
                            echo "
                         <div class='sl-item b-success'>
                         <div class='sl-icon'>
                         <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
                          </div>
                            <div class='sl-item b-info'>
                                <div class='sl-content'>
                                    <div class='sl-date text-muted'>". $messagesList['t'] ."
                                    <span class='pull-right'>Name: " . strtoUpper($messagesList['n']) . " </span>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                    <div> " .$messagesList['m']. 
                                    "<span> 
                            <button onclick='clear_alarm(" . $message_key . ")' class='btn btn-sm white pull-right'> Clear </span> </button> </div>
                                    
                                    <div>
                                </div>
                            </div>";
                         }
                         
                         
                     ?>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Your issue is most likely around the usage of `"`.  If the value of `$message_key` is a string, your source is going to look like `onclick='clear_alarm(mystringvalue)'`.  In which case javascript is going to treat that string as a variable reference, not a literal.

Answer (score 2):

If `$message_key` is a string, you need to put quotes around it.

```
<button onclick='clear_alarm(\"" . $message_key . "\")' class='btn btn-sm white pull-right'> Clear </span> </button> </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the backslash for actually?

Comment: @DennisOng It's the escape character, to make the double quote be treated as a literal.  `var x = "\"";`  or `var x = '\'';` as different examples.  That's javascript but the same syntax works in PHP as well, iirc.

Comment: If you don't escape the double quote, it will end the PHP string instead of being put into the string. @DennisOng

Comment: Oh, what if i have two variables in the functions?

Comment: Put quotes around each of them, and separate them with commas. `clear_alarm(\"" . $var1 . "\", \"" . $var2 . "\")`

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar !